# Редактирование строки таблицы по нажатию на кнопку (чистый JS)

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста реализовать следующую задачу (или хотя бы направить в нужное русло):

1. Когда жмем на кнопку "Edit" (карандаш) - из соответствующей строчки значения  колонок `tdItem`, `tdQuant` и `tdPrice` должны поместиться в соответствующие инпуты в верхнем блоке.
2. Кнопка "Add" должна сменить значение на "Update".
3. Редактируем данные и сохраняем нажимая на кнопку "Update".
4. Та строка, в которой мы проводили изменения, должна поменять значения на вновь введенные.

**P.S.** Упростил листинг, для удобства оставил самое необходимое.
Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы!

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';
  checkbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(event)');

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'image';
  btnEdit.className = 'btn';
  btnEdit.src = 'icons/edit.png';
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btn';
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdNum = document.createElement("td");
  tdNum.setAttribute('id', 'td1_id');
  tdNum.className = 'td_num';
  tdNum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var tdDone = document.createElement("td");
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdQuant = document.createElement("td");
  tdQuant.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.className = 'td_action';
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdNum);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

}

function editButton() {
  //обработка редактирования строки...

  localStorage.setItem('DoneList', document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Shopping List</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/shortcut_add.ico" />
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td class='td'>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так. Дописал функцию`editButton`, дополнил ее логикой. Также дополнил функцию `insertRow`, чтобы определять какая кнопка (обновления или добавления). Добавил функцию `updateRow`. Чистый JavaScript, как и просили. Код дополнен комментариями.

Для соблюдения уникальности и исключения случайной ошибки, я бы рекомендовал использовать не [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), а [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) для единичных элементов. Просто класс могут использовать по чистой случайности и потом придется искать ошибку, лучше использовать идентификатор, чтобы минимизировать коллизии (соответственно, нужно добавить аттрибут `id` для таких элементов).

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  // получаем нашу кнопку и смотрим на ее текст, если Update - будем обновлять
  var inputButton = document.getElementsByClassName('input_button')[0];
  if (inputButton.innerText == "Update") {
    updateRow(inputButton); // передадим кнопку в метод
    return false;
  }

  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';
  checkbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(event)');

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'image';
  btnEdit.className = 'btn';
  btnEdit.src = 'icons/edit.png';
  btnEdit.value = "Edit"; // для наглядности
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton(this);
    return false;
  });

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btn';
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.value = "Delete"; // для наглядности
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdNum = document.createElement("td");
  tdNum.setAttribute('id', 'td1_id');
  tdNum.className = 'td_num';
  tdNum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var tdDone = document.createElement("td");
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdQuant = document.createElement("td");
  tdQuant.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.className = 'td_action';
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdNum);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

  document.getElementsByClassName('input_add')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByClassName('input_quant')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByClassName('input_price')[0].value = "";

  return false;
}

function updateRow(inputButton) {
  // indexRow - не нужно уменьшать на единицу, так как первая - это заголовок
  // получим изменяемую строку по индесу записанному в value кнопки обновления
  var row = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[inputButton.value]; 
  row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  // получим значения введенные в инпуты
  var inputAdd = document.getElementsByClassName('input_add')[0];
  var inputQuant = document.getElementsByClassName('input_quant')[0];
  var inputPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('input_price')[0];
  // обновим значения ячеек в строке
  row.cells[2].innerText = inputAdd.value;
  row.cells[3].innerText = inputQuant.value;
  row.cells[4].innerText = inputPrice.value;
  // поменяем значение кнопки обратно и очистим инпуты
  inputButton.innerText = "Add";
  inputButton.value = "";
  inputAdd.value = "";
  inputQuant.value = "";
  inputPrice.value = "";
}

function editButton(btn) {
  //обработка редактирования строки...
  // получим стркоу
  var tr = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  tr.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  
  // получим значения из строки
  var valueItem = tr.cells[2].innerText;
  var valueQuantity = tr.cells[3].innerText;
  var valuePrice = tr.cells[4].innerText;
  // заполним инпуты значениями из строки
  document.getElementsByClassName('input_add')[0].value = valueItem;
  document.getElementsByClassName('input_quant')[0].value = valueQuantity;
  document.getElementsByClassName('input_price')[0].value = valuePrice;
  // получим нашу кнопку
  var inputButton = document.getElementsByClassName('input_button')[0];
  inputButton.innerText = "Update"; // меняем текст
  inputButton.value = tr.cells[0].innerText; // в value будем хранить индекс строки
  
  // данный блок не работает в сниппете
  // localStorage.setItem('DoneList', document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Shopping List</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/shortcut_add.ico" />
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable'); value=''">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td class='td'>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш пример помог. По мелочи еще сделал изменение цвета кнопки Update для наглядности, заменил   `btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton(this);
    return false;
  });` на `btnEdit.setAttribute('onclick', 'editButton(this)');` для того чтобы при сохранении в локалсторадж и перезагрузке страницы событие на кнопке оставалось. Сейчас еще сделаю чтобы редактируемая строка тоже меняла цвет и будет как раз то, что нужно!

Comment: @TheHateInMe ага, хорошо :) еще обратите внимание на `getElementsByClassName`, про что я писал в ответе, мне кажется так будет правильнее.

Comment: Да, обращу на это внимание чуть позже, спасибо.

Comment: В функции `editButton(btnEdit)`  пробую изменить цвет редактируемой строки, цвет меняется, но как только курсор уходит со строки, она принимает первоначальный цвет:
`var tr = btnEdit.parentNode.parentNode;
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`

Comment: @TheHateInMe странно, тут в сниппете все работает с изменением цвета...

Comment: да.. тут работает... а у меня на локальной машине ни в опере ни в хроме не хочет

Comment: @TheHateInMe возможно у вас подключены какие-то стили, которые это меняют...типо Bootstrap фрймворка.

Comment: да, не бутстрап... точняк, у меня просто при наведении мыши на строку уже цвет меняется на серый

Comment: `function lightingRows() {
    var row = document.getElementsByClassName("row_class");
[].forEach.call(row, function (row) {
        row.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#ececec";
        });
        row.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });
    });
}`

Comment: Да уж, не подумал что выйдет такая накладка....Только зря время потратил, Наверное надо было сделать прсто строки в таблице через одну серая-белая, а я загнался и подкрашивал серым цветом строку в фокусе. А теперь при нажатии на редактирование она подкрашивает желтым, но как только я сдвигаю мышь срабатывает событие `mouseover`

Comment: Кстати, попробуй в сниппете создать несколько строк и в каждой нажать Edit

Comment: @TheHateInMe ну это уже нюансы :) можно добавить цикл, пробежать по всем строкам - сделать их белыми, а лишь потом менять цвет выбранной строки :) главное идея, а тут ты уже сам допилишь, я думаю

Comment: Да, буду дальше голову ломать)) Спасибо за помощь)